# Generic way of validating the structure of javascript class

Tags: javascript, typescript

So I have a provider class

```
export class Provider {

    activeAccount: boolean;
    description: String;
    name: String;
    providerType: any;
    publicUrl: String;
    uuid: String;

    isValidStructure(obj){

        let keys = Object.keys(obj), valid = true,

        properties = ['activeAccount', 'description', 'name', 'providerType', 'publicUrl', 'uuid']

        keys.forEach((key)=>{
            if(!properties.includes(key)){
                valid = false
            }
        })

        return valid
    }

}
```

I have a method to validate that the data used to create the model is a property of the model, it works but is there a generic way of doing this

The properties array is hardcoded in the function isValidStructure

```
        let validData: any = {name: 'some name'}
        let invalidData: any = {namexx: 'the key is invalid'}
        let provider = Object.assign(new Provider(), validData)
        let provider2 = Object.assign(new Provider(), invalidData)

        provider.isValidStructure(validData)//true
        provider2.isValidStructure(invalidData)//false
```

Above is some examples of the function and its output
Is there some way of getting the properties of the class

Comment: Create the `properties` array in the constructor of the class?

Comment: @HereticMonkey I don't want to do this as it is too much overhead, I want to use one data object that has all or some of the valid properties

Comment: Then pass the list of valid properties to the `isValidStructure` function... That would be the only way to make it "generic". Otherwise, TypeScript can do the validation at compile time (without a function), if you set the types correctly.

Comment: Maybe a work of mine could help: https://itnext.io/bringing-typescript-types-at-runtime-with-typeonly-c317e9dd8880 .

Comment: can you just have your class implement an interface which is the same type as your constructor obj?

Comment: @Scrimothy could you show me an example

Comment: Will the data you validate ever come from external input (network, filesystem, database, user input..)?

Comment: So you want to have dynamic validation? – lucifer63 Look at io-ts, https://www.olioapps.com/blog/checking-types-real-world-typescript/

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to get a list of properties of the defined-`class` in javascript or out-of-the-box solution for typescript, you have to manually inject it.

```
   export class Provider {
      static properties = [...]
   }

   /// or
   Provider.properties = []
```

Answer (score 0):

You could define an interface that has all the common properties between the class and your passed in config `obj` and then have your class implement it and your constructor take that type as a param.

```
export interface IProvider {
    activeAccount?: boolean;
    description?: String;
    name?: String;
    providerType?: any;
    publicUrl?: String;
    uuid?: String;
}

export class Provider implements IProvider {
    activeAccount: boolean;
    description: String;
    name: String;
    providerType: any;
    publicUrl: String;
    uuid: String;

    constructor(obj?: IProvider) {
        if (obj) {
            this.activeAccount = obj.activeAccount;
            ...
        }
    }

}

const provider = new Provider({...});
```

**UPDATE**

If none/any of the properties are required, you could add a `?` in the interface between the prop name and colon. That way you can allow the constructor obj have as many of the valid props as it needs, but it would still raise an error if you try to pass in:

```
const provider = new Provider({ invalid: true });
```

Take a look at [Typescript Interfaces](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html) for more info

**UPDATE 2**

To put this back into your original example:

```
let validData: any = {name: 'some name'}
let invalidData: any = {namexx: 'the key is invalid'}
let provider = Object.assign(new Provider(), validData)
let provider2 = Object.assign(new Provider(), invalidData)
```

Defining both `validData` and `invalidData` as `any` will force Typescript not to yell at you with red squigglies because it basically says "this might be an `IProvider`". So you should set `validData: IProvider` instead of `any`.

Also, the same thing happens with `Object.assign()` when adding props to a class instance. It appears that Typescript doesn't mind that you're attempting to put in invalid props if you do this:

```
const validData: IProvider = { name: 'some name' };
const invalidData: any = { namexx: 'the key is invalid' };
const provider: Provider = Object.assign(new Provider(validData), invalidData);

// Provider { name: 'some name', namexx: 'the key is invalid' }
```

However, if you again change `any` to `IProvider` on `invalidData: IProvider`, it'll yell at you for the `namexx` prop in there.

That all said, since typing and validating seems to be important to you, then you should try to ensure that all types are explicitly declared to allow Typescript to do what it does.

Comment: When I pass {name: 'some name'} to the constructor my variable has no properties, let provider = new Provider(validData)

Comment: And how would I be able to valid the structure this way?

Comment: I just updated my answer to address your first question. For the second one, if you pass in a property that isn't a part of the `IProvider` interface, then you'll get red squigglies and compiler errors.

Comment: Also, you'll still need to still need to set all the instance props to the obj props in the constructor like `this.name = obj.name`, but I left that out for simplicity of focusing on your question